# How to specify / select a particular property of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, data-structures

I am creating a react web app. My state in my parent component is an array of objects (one to many number of objects stored in this array...it could be any number of objects). I want to send object X of the array through to my child component through props. Here is my child component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Card extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log('in card');
        console.log(this.props.newCard);
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Here is a card!</h2>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Card
```

For necessary context, here is my render method in the parent component that calls the child (named Card):

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Card newCard={this.state.cardList[this.state.eachCard]}></Card>
                <button>Next</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The this.state.eachCard is just referring to an accumulator I will later implement to go through each object of the array upon clicking the Next button. Right now it is just set to position 0 for testing purposes.

When I console.log the newCard prop in the child component, this is the structure of the object that is send from parent to child:

```
{CardID: 3, CardName: "test", CardDefinition: "testing", category_CategoryID: 2}
```

However, I am wanting to specify a particular property of this object. For example, I want to retrieve the name of the card. However, when I tried to console.log this

```
console.log(this.props.newCard.CardName);
```

I received the following error:

```
"Cannot read property 'CardName' of undefined"
```

This does not make sense to me, as this.props.newCard was not undefined. Therefore it would make sense to me that specifying the newCard prop one more degree to newCard.CardName should logically work. I cannot figure out what I am missing. Is this some sort of syntax error? Or is my logic just totally off?
I seem to be very close, but am hung up on how to proceed...any ideas sure would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post how are you calling this component in the parent, please?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted as shown in this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-gould-ulugu?file=/src/Card.js, what happens if you log `newCard` and `newCard.CardName` at the same time?

Comment: I continue to get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good first step would be to guard against undefined here. I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like but if there's some async happening somewhere it's possible on first render that the prop is undefined. When you pass undefined in to console.log it doesn't log anything so if this component is indeed getting rendered twice then you'd get no log for the first render. A great way to test this theory is to do your console log like the following:

`console.log('newCard', this.props.newCard);`

You can also guard against undefined here so it won't throw an error by returning null if this.props.newCard is in fact undefined.

```
export class Card extends Component {

    render() {
        if (this.props.newCard === undefined) {
          return null;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Here is a card!</h2>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Card
```

Edit due to additional context.

The way you render items in an array as children in react is using the map method of the array object and passing in a component to the callback:

```
        return (
            <div>
                {
                  this.state.cardList.map(eachCard => (<Card newCard={eachCard} />))
                }
                <button>Next</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your console log, change `porps` by `props`.

Comment: This typo did not exist in my original code. I have fixed it in the post. The problem persists.

Comment: Ok so please give us more of your code, you wholde child and parent component please. Also, where does the structure of the object you gave us comes from ? your child or your parent ?

Comment: I just added this info the the original post. The entire child component is included, as well as the render method for the parent component. The object structure I included is being sent from the parent to the child and is printed in the child.

Comment: So I suppose that this line `this.state.cardList[this.state.eachCard]` return `undefined ` when your component is rendered. Does your data comes from an Async call ? if yes, then you have to wait for your data to be loaded before to render your component: `return( if(!this.sate.data) { return <Loader /> } else { // your actual stuff })`